# vue js Поиск внутри массива

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Есть массив объектов:

movies = [{
    name: "Amovie1",
    year : 2011
}, 
{
    name: "Bmovie2",
    year: 2012
},
{
    name: "Cmovie3",
    year: 2013
}];

Есть поле

```html
<input 
                            type="text"
                            placeholder="Найти фильм...">
                        <button
```

При вводе нового значения в поле, например Am - элемент, который соответствует параметрам поиска, остается, а остальные временно скрываются

Прочитала информацию насчет метода filtered
Думаю, это то, что мне нужно. НО. Как мне прописать вызов этой функции в Html? 
Какая директива подойдет? И как грамотно прописать эту функцию в моем случае?

Answer (score 2):

Дополню ответ Alex Sazonov.

Лучше в этом случае использовать computed, чтобы не менять исходные данные

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      movies: [
        { name: "Amovie1", year : 2011 }, 
        { name: "Bmovie2", year: 2012 }, 
        { name: "Cmovie3", year: 2013 }
      ],
      inputStr: ''
    }
  },
  computed: {
    filteredMovies() {
      if (this.inputStr) {
        return this.movies.filter(item => {
            return item.name.includes(this.inputStr);
        });
      }
      return this.movies
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <input type="text" v-model="inputStr">
  <ul>
    <li v-for="(item, index) of filteredMovies" :key="index">{{ item.name }}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div>
  <input type="text" v-model="inputStr" @keyup="sortArray">
  <ul>
    <li v-for="(item, index) of list" :key="index">{{ item.name }}</li>
  </ul>
</div>


created() {
    this.list = this.movies;
}
data() {
  return {
    movies: [
      { name: "Amovie1", year : 2011 }, 
      { name: "Bmovie2", year: 2012 }, 
      { name: "Cmovie3", year: 2013 }
    ],
    inputStr: '',
    list: [],
  }
},
methods: {
  sortArray() {
    this.list = this.movies.filter(item => {
      return item.name.includes(this.inputStr);
    });
  }
}
```

По идее вот так должно работать. Проверил. Работает.