# Поиск элементов по массиву

Tags: javascript, vue.js

При поиске нужного мне элемента, который я ввел в инпут, у меня вылазит ошибка, что

> item.himid.includes is not a function
> как это исправить ?

```js
const app = new Vue({
   el: '#app',
   data() {
      return {
         pepFractions: [
            {name: 'Qweqweqw M.', himid: 129},
            {name: 'WQEasad M.', himid: 249},
            {name: 'DFHdfh M.', himid: 49},
            {name: 'AESAEa M.', himid: 129},
            {name: 'Qweqweqw M.', himid: 49},
            {name: 'DFHAdhfda M.', himid: 19},
            {name: 'EWEt M.', himid: 19},
            {name: 'SDfsdgsdg M.', himid: 49},
            {name: 'Afgasfas M.', himid: 49},
            {name: 'Qweqweqw M.', himid: 3469},
            {name: 'Qweqweqw M.', himid: 6439},
            {name: 'EQWevzdvzdv M.', himid: 934},
            {name: 'DGdsagsd M.', himid: 349},
            {name: 'Qweqweqw M.', himid: 5439},
            {name: 'ASDgsdf M.', himid: 9},
         ],
         findid: ''
      }
   },
   methods: {

   },
   computed: {
      filteredID() {
         if (this.findid) {
           return this.pepFractions.filter(item => {
               return item.himid.includes(this.findid);
           });
         }
         return this.pepFractions
       }
   }
});
```

```css
.member__list {
                  width: 1323px;
                  height: 363px;
                  margin-top: 17px;
                  overflow-y: scroll;
                  display: flex;
                  flex-wrap: wrap;
                  border-radius: 24px;
}
.member__item {
  width: 250px;
  height: 170px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.12);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}
.item-nln-nam {
                           font-family: 'Montserrat';
                           font-style: normal;
                           font-weight: 700;
                           font-size: 32px;
                           line-height: 39px;               
                           color: #000000; 
                           letter-spacing: -0.08em;  
                        }  
.item-info__text {                     
                           font-family: 'Montserrat';
                           font-style: normal;
                           font-weight: 600;
                           font-size: 18px;
                           line-height: 18px;
                           display: flex;
                           align-items: center;
                           letter-spacing: -0.04em;
                           color: #000000;
                        }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
<input v-model="findid" type="text">
 <div class="member__list">
  <div class="member__item" v-for="(item,index) in filteredID">
        <div class="item-nln-nam">{{item.name}}</div>
        <div class="item-info__text">ID {{item.himid}}</div>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: У вас `item.himid` это число а не массив

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/961549/vue-js-Поиск-внутри-массива делал по этому примеру , но в его ответах там все работает (

Comment: Подумайте над TypeScript или JSDoc... Много таких проблем уйдет само собой

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответ с учетом комментария.

Вы осуществляете поиск по числу, поэтому в вашем случае `includes` не работает. Нет такого метода у типа Number.

Для чисел нужно явное сравнение

```
filteredID() {
  if (this.findid) {
    return this.pepFractions.filter(item => {
      return item.himid === this.findid;
    });
  }
  return this.pepFractions
}
```

Если `this.findid` строка, преобразуем в число

```
filteredID() {
  if (this.findid) {
    return this.pepFractions.filter(item => {
      return item.himid === Number(this.findid);
    });
  }
  return this.pepFractions
}
```

Когда надо найти вхождение числа в число, то можно сделать так(При условии, что this.findid это строка):

```
filteredID() {
  if (this.findid) {
    return this.pepFractions.filter(item => {
      return item.himid.toString().inclused(this.findid);
    });
  }
  return this.pepFractions
}
```

Если искать например по name то тогда можно использовать incluses, так как name это строка и у строк есть метод [includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes)

```
filteredID() {
  if (this.findid) {
    return this.pepFractions.filter(item => {
      return item.name.inclused(this.findid);
    });
  }
  return this.pepFractions
}
```

Что бы не схватывать такие ошибки, опишите ваш проект с помощью JSDoc. Если ваша IDE умеет с ним работать, много ошибок может быть устранено на этапе написания кода.

Comment: При помощи поиска по name, все работает, а вот когда я веду поиск по айди, при вводе числа сразу пропадают все элементы , хотя число которое я ввел , есть в их himid

Comment: А вы ищите часть числа? или полное совпадение?

Comment: я ищу часть числа

Comment: @Дмитрий если делаете поиск по числу, то ` this.findid` в  `item.himid === this.findid` нужно привести к числу, так как в данный момент попадает строка

Comment: @Дмитрий Обновил ответ. Добавил вариант поиска цифры в числе )

Answer (score 1):

Если используете код из примера, то там используется `item.name` а не `item.year`

И вы тогда делайте так же, сейчас вы делаете так: `item.himid` а нужно так чтобы работало `item.name`

И `return` в этой сроке можно не писать `return item.himid.includes(this.findid);`

Рабочий пример:

```js
const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      pepFractions: [{
          name: 'Qweqweqw M.',
          himid: 129
        },
        {
          name: 'WQEasad M.',
          himid: 249
        },
        {
          name: 'DFHdfh M.',
          himid: 49
        },
        {
          name: 'AESAEa M.',
          himid: 129
        },
        {
          name: 'Qweqweqw M.',
          himid: 49
        },
        {
          name: 'DFHAdhfda M.',
          himid: 19
        },
        {
          name: 'EWEt M.',
          himid: 19
        },
        {
          name: 'SDfsdgsdg M.',
          himid: 49
        },
        {
          name: 'Afgasfas M.',
          himid: 49
        },
        {
          name: 'Qweqweqw M.',
          himid: 3469
        },
        {
          name: 'Qweqweqw M.',
          himid: 6439
        },
        {
          name: 'EQWevzdvzdv M.',
          himid: 934
        },
        {
          name: 'DGdsagsd M.',
          himid: 349
        },
        {
          name: 'Qweqweqw M.',
          himid: 5439
        },
        {
          name: 'ASDgsdf M.',
          himid: 9
        },
      ],
      findid: ''
    }
  },
  methods: {

  },
  computed: {
    filteredID() {
      if (this.findid) {
        return this.pepFractions.filter((item) => item.name.includes(this.findid))
      }
      return this.pepFractions
    }
  }
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: Roboto;
}

.member__list {
  width: 1323px;
  height: 363px;
  margin-top: 17px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  border-radius: 24px;
}

.member__item {
  width: 250px;
  height: 170px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.12);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}

.item-nln-nam {
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 32px;
  line-height: 39px;
  color: #000000;
  letter-spacing: -0.08em;
}

.item-info__text {
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 18px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  letter-spacing: -0.04em;
  color: #000000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div class="" id="app">
  <input v-model="findid" type="text">
  <div class="member__list">
    <div class="member__item" v-for="(item,index) in filteredID">
      <div class="item-nln-nam">{{item.name}}</div>
      <div class="item-info__text">ID {{item.himid}}</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```